# Category/genre name for games like: Ogame, Kings of Chaos, and Bitefight.?

Tags: browser-based-games

I'm searching for a category name for games like: Ogame, Kings of Chaos, and Bitefight.

When I learned about those, they were just called browser games, but today where we have the technology to create every genre of games in the browser, I miss a box to put these: 'only text, pictures and no fancy animation-games' into.

Do they actually have a name, leading to my Google-Fu being miserable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are called browser based games as you've guessed.

There are many technologies used to create browser based games however. You may want to limit your searches to technologies that don't support 3D or advanced gameplay. For example, searching for PHP browser games or HTML 4 browser games would likely limit you to the only-text-pictures-and-no-fancy-animation-games you're looking for. Further, you can search for 'Text based browser games', even though it sounds like it's limited to text only, these frequently include images as well like the games you've listed.

Comment: A couple more terms used lightly: PBBG, PBBRPG.